# Pass pointer to function

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

I am learning pointers.

```
int main() {
   int a = 2;
   cal(&a);
}

void cal(int* a) {
   //Here:
  //What does the value of a mean?
  //What does the value of &a mean?
}
```

As you see above, in `main()`, I passed the address of a to function `cal(int* a)`.

I am wondering what is the meaning of value `a` and `&a` in `cal(int*)` ?

Is `a` in `cal(int*)` represents the address of `a` in `main()` ?

Is `&a` in `cal(int*)` represents only the address which points to the address of `a` in `main()`?

Comment: Yes you are correct on both accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` variable in main() function is an integer variable.
`a`  variable which is an argument in function cal() is pointer to integer  which will point or hold the address of variable  `a` in main() .

Is a in cal(int*) represents the address of a in main() ?

**yes**

Is &a in cal(int*) represents only the address which points to the address of a in main()?

**yes**

&a in cal() means address of variable `a` in cal() that holds the address of `a` in main() function.

From your example ,you might have got confused by the usage of same variables names.But there scope is limited to there respective fucntions and they dont conflict.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the value of &a mean?

Take the address of `a`. This is done by applying the address-operator `&` to the `int` variable `a`.

> What does the value of a mean?

Inside `cal()` `a` represents the address of an `int` as having been passed when calling `cal()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the your code you have two scopes:

On the main scope 'a' is a variable with value 2, and a pointer to it.
You pass the pointer to the function 'cal'.

On the cal scope 'a' is the pointer given as an input from the main function. &a would be the pointer to the pointer, and conversely *a is the value the pointer point to (which is 2).